# Calculate a value for a column in a WebGrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I'm trying to calculate a column value using two properties of the DataSource.
This is my column:

```
grid.Column(header:"Duration", format:@<text>@{((TimeSpan)(item.EndTime - item.StartTime)).TotalMilliseconds}</text>)))
```

I keep getting an HTTPCompileException when I try to navigate to this grid. Why is it unhappy with this?

Comment: not sure if you should be using `@{ }` instead of `@( )`

Comment: @JamieD77 Add it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to remove the {} from the format block.